# Converting unbound DataGridView to a DataTable

Tags: c#, class, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to convert my datagridview `dgvInput` from `Form1` to a `DataTable` in an another class `Queries` in preparation for `SqlBulkCopy`. I pass `dgvInput` to a method `SaveAll` in my class `Queries` with a parameter `DataGridView dgv`.

Form1:

```
public void convert2DT(DataGridView dgv)
{
    Queries qry = new Queries();
    qry.SaveAll(dgvInput);
}
```

Class:

```
class Queries {

public void SaveAll(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
        {
            //Create table and insert into cell value.
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
            >>  { dataRow[i] = DateTime.Parse(dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString()); }
                else if (i == 7)
                { dataRow[i] = int.Parse(dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString()); }
                else
                { dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString(); }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    //SqlBulkCopy Codes
    }
}
```

I'm getting NullReferenceException on line `>>`.
Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I have tried setting `New` to the `dgv`. However, I still get an Exception. From what I've researched the Nested for loops SHOULD do the job right.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: either `dr.Cells[i]` or `dr.Cells[i].Value` is `null`. Likely it is `dr.Cells[i]`. Use null conditional operator.

Comment: Thank You! `dr.Cells[i].Value` is `null`. Specifically the 1st row it generates is null. Can I somehow delete that null row??

Comment: @Ian NVM. I just found out why its null. my last row is blank. Just set `AllowUserToAddRows = false`. Thank You for the Help. Please post your answer below. So I could accept it.

Comment: OK, as requested, an answer is put up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your `dr.Cells[i].Value` is `null` and that is caused by the empty last row due to the option `AllowUserToAddRows = true` as you figure out later. To solve it, you *might* put `AllowUserToAddRows = false` as what you have done.

But better still to check if `dr.Cells[i].Value` is not `null` before processing it to make it more robust towards `null` cell value wherever it may be found:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
{
    if (dr.Cells[i].Value == null)
        continue; //don't process
    if (i == 0)
    { dataRow[i] = DateTime.Parse(dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString()); }
    else if (i == 7)
    { dataRow[i] = int.Parse(dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString()); }
    else
    { dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString(); }
}
```

And use `continue` to ignore the `null` cell. Use `AllowUserToAddRows = false` only if you really mean it; that is, to prevent user to add rows, not to protect against cell's `null` value.